# Prove what algorithm does and its time complexity?

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms

```
int randomFunction(int x){  
     int y = 0;
     while(x >= 1){
       x = round(x/3);
       y++;
    }
    return y;
}
```

This code is written in Java and I have to prove how the algorithm works and it's time complexity.

I only get the time complexity which is O (n), I made some trace by replacing x with integer numbers higher than 0 but I still don't get the pattern in term of x.

Comment: Hint: See what values it returns for $3,9,27,81,$

Comment: Hint. You probably didn't try large enough sample values of $x$. Try $3$, $9$, $27$. Another hint: what does this algorithm do when you replace the hardcoded $3$ by $10$? That should help you both with what the algorithm does and its time complexity.

Comment: when I execute the code; (x=3,y=2) , (x=9, y=3),(x=27, y=4),(x=81, y=5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ignore the round function for a moment, it is counting the number of times you can divide the input by $3$ and stay greater than $1$, so it is essentially the base $3$ log of $x$.  The round function tweaks that a bit, but doesn't change much.

Comment: I still don't get the log part. So the complexity should be like O( log n) ?

Comment: In your last comment on the question, you have $y=1+\log_3(x)$